# MySQL GROUP BY and COUNT over Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a MySQL Table as follows:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID |  MON  |  TUE  |  WED  |  THU  |  FRI  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  0 |  Bike |  Bike |  Walk |  Bike |  Car  |
|  1 |  Car  |  Car  |  Car  |  Bus  |  Car  |
|  2 |  Bus  | Train |  Bus  |  Bus  | Train |
|  3 |  Car  |  Car  |  Car  |  Walk |  Car  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

How would I group by and count all days, to get the total modes of each transport over the week. For example:

```
+--------+-------+
|  MODE  | COUNT |
+--------+-------+
|  Bike  |   3   |
|   Bus  |   4   |
|   Car  |   9   |
|  Train |   2   |
|  Walk  |   2   |
+--------+-------+
```

I have tried using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Mon 
FROM transport 
GROUP BY Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri
```

But this creates a new group for each unique value in each day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to produce a subquery that selects the transport mode in one column using the `union all` operator, and then counting the occurrences:

```
SELECT   mode, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT mon AS mode FROM transport UNION ALL
          SELECT tue AS mode FROM transport UNION ALL
          SELECT wed AS mode FROM transport UNION ALL
          SELECT thu AS mode FROM transport UNION ALL
          SELECT fri AS mode FROM transport) t
GROUP BY mode
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a separate table of modes, you can also do:

```
select m.mode, count(*)
from modes m join
     transport t
     on m.mode in (t.mon, t.tue, t.wed, t.thu, t.fri)
group by m.mode;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mode, COUNT(*)FROM(SELECT mon AS mode FROM transport UNION ALL
          SELECT tue AS mode FROM transport UNION ALL
          SELECT wed AS mode FROM transport UNION ALL
          SELECT thu AS mode FROM transport UNION ALL
          SELECT fri AS mode FROM transport) t
GROUP BY mode
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).